# How many roots has $x^a=b$ where $a$ is a real number?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I know that $x^a=b$ has $a$ complex roots if $a$ is an entire number. What can I say about $a$ real?

I've tried some Wolfram Calculations with exponent $n \pi$ and had $[n\pi]+1$ complex roots... So I've thought about $[a]+1$, but cannot prove it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to give some explanation of what you have done and where you are stuck in this.

Comment: @N.Owad I've edited, thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $x^a$ when $a$ is not an integer? Say a fraction, or even $a=\pi.$

Comment: @coffeemath, well... When a fraction, $x^{p/q}=\sqrt[q]{x^p}$... $a$ not rational by limits on rationals... So I could conclude that I can only look to rationals? Thank you!

Comment: I still think irrational exponents can be defined, but it gets complicated as far as I know.

Comment: Irrational exponents are taken as the continuous limit of rational exponents, and these are well defined for $x\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $x=re^{i\phi}$
then:
$$r^ae^{i\phi a}=b$$
since:
$$|e^{i\phi a}|=1$$ be must have that:
$$|r^a|=|b|$$
or:
$$r=|b|^{1/a}$$
now roots will repeat at a point since $e^{iz}$ has a period of $2\pi$ and so you want to find all $\phi$ which satisfy the equation:
$$e^{i\phi a}=1=e^{2\pi i}=e^{0i}$$
in other words, find all unique $\phi$ for integer $k$ such that:
$$\phi a=2k\pi$$

---

From all of this we get:
$$\phi=\frac{2k\pi}{a},\qquad 0\le\phi\le2\pi$$
Hopefully you can see where this is going

Comment: This assumes $b$ is real, but the gist of it is correct.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yeah I'm a little rusty on this area haha but It seemed to be okay for $b\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @HenryLee thank you so much! But I think you considered $b$ positive. If $b$ negative, so $\phi a=2k\pi+\pi,$ am I right? Thank you!

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @HenryLee I am sorry if I am stucked with this... But if $a$ is irrational, so $2\pi k/a$ is not a periodic function, so there's infinite many roots...? But why the roots of $x^e=2$ are $3$ and the roots of $x^{2e}=2$ are $5$, for instance? Thank you so much! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ee%3D2; https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%282e%29%3D2

Comment: @HenryLee: other doubt: Why this equation has no complex root? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%280.2%29%3D-1 I could take $k=0$, so $\phi=\pi $... Why $e^{\pi i}=-1$ is not a solution? I imagine that this relation with my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171374/why-wolfram-do-18-9-so-strange?noredirect=1#comment8640687_4171374, but not sure

Comment: @Quiet_waters : As in [your other Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171374/why-wolfram-do-18-9-so-strange), Wolfram Alpha is giving what amounts to "the small roots" (the roots with complex argument in $[-\pi, \pi]$ (and it may exclude one of those endpoints; I don't recall)).  However, there are countably infinitely many solutions.  The set of such solutions is being described in this Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @EricTowers